# Always importing too many classes... I think

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I have a basic problem with knowing which classes to import for a given application, renderer, AS package, mxml component, etc.  There seems to be hundreds of classes (both mx and flash) and I'm never sure which one(s) to import... so I just keep adding import statements until the errors go away.  Is there a reference somewhere that I don't know about?  Or does this just come with experience?  Also... does importing a load of classes actually make the file size larger or does Flex only import the classes used nregardless of what I specify?  If it only uses what is needed, why wouldn't everyone just do: import mx.*;

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/index.html

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that if you find yourself bringing in tons of imports, you should ask yourself: Does this class do to much?

It is less of a technical issue, and more of problem of object-oriented design -- maintainability, testability and stability.

I do my best to limit my external dependencies.  I try to conform to [SOLID principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_%28object-oriented_design%29) that tell me that classes should exist for one reason.  If a class does too much, it is a "code smell" and an indication that you should split it up.

How much is too much?  It is tough to have a specific litmus test or limit... I just ask myself "What does this class do"?  If my answer contains an "and" in it, then I consider splitting it up.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is a not a real problem if you use any half decent IDE. If you're not using one, you probably should (even if it's not stricly necessary and you can write and compile with notepad and the command line).

If you are using Flex/Flash Builder, it will add the imports automatically (and remove the unneeded ones as well). Also, you can use `Ctrl` + `SPACE` to prompt autocomplete, which should add the necessary imports.

Flash Develop also manages this for you (the shortcut was `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `1` if I recall correctly, but I haven't used FD for a while).

There are other IDEs out there that I haven't personally used but also have this very basic feature.

If you're using the Flash IDE, well, it really sucks for writting code, so you should probably consider writting your code in some other less brain-dead editor if you plan to do anything more than a couple of lines of code here and there (again, you can write code in the Flash IDE but why not taking advantage of better tools when they're available?).

Comment: i do my programming in Flash IDE.  lol.  there have been improvements for coding in Flash CS5.  Flash Builder 4, while loaded with options and conveniences, doesn't allow me to format my code blocks the way i want - which simply drives me crazy.  also, not that this matters to most developers, but FB4 has a seriously ugly UI.

Comment: +1 for FlashDevelop, it's free and if you're on a PC not excuse not to use it.

Comment: Well, I used the IDE for coding for years, until I found SEPY (AS 2.0 days) and MTASC. Then I switched to FD and then to FB3. Not that I love it; at times it feels like a beta and in many ways (as an editor at least) FD is superior. But I got spoiled by having a debugger that actually works, so I find it hard going back to `trace`... If they managed to make the debugger work in FD, I would perhaps consider using it as my main IDE, though. But Flash, I don't know. I feel Adobe managed to make it worse with every new major release. The last sane one I used was Flash 8 (I haven't used CS5 though)

Answer (score 0):

When you get an error, look at the [API Reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/index.html) for the class, and then either import the whole package or just the class you want.  Highlighting the class and hitting F1 should also work (but I never search help this way).

As for file size, see my answer on [Is it possible to dynamically create an instance of user-defined Class in Action Script 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670466/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-create-an-instance-of-user-defined-class-in-action/4671934#4671934)

Answer (score 0):

As Juan pointed out, use FlashDevelop, it is a great (and free) IDE.

If you're using FlashDevelop with the Flex Compiler, you can compile straight from FlashDevelop, and use the refactoring tools they offer to slim down your imports.

Aside from that though, if you're not referencing them, they don't get compiled, so it's not like your compiled swf is any bigger.